# How to find a device /dev with a specific $string preferably in PHP

Tags: php, linux, midi

I am reading/writing from/to a midi device. The device is (partly) listed as "ME-50" in e.g. a lsusb. What command can I use to recognise the exact device the "ME-50" is linked to? In my main PC e.g. it is linked to /dev/snd/midiC0D0, but it could also be /dev/snd/midiC2D0 depending on what is plugged in first.

something like:

```
for all devices in /dev/snd/midi* {
    if substring in the device = "ME-50"
         return device (/dev/snd/midiC0D0 or midiC1D0 or midiC2D0....)
}
```

a bash command would do, but I am programming in PHP so if PHP has something simple to find the device....

Thanks
Arjen

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into the path `/dev/snd/by-id` if you are luck your device will show up with some recognizable name.

Then use [scandir](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) or alike to iterate the path.

If you want to get the direct path from the link, you can use [readlink](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.readlink.php).

**Edit:**

If `udevadm` is available the command returns a lot of information on the devices, which might contain identifiable bits. The following snippet iterates the available midi devices and stores all information in an array (`$result`), e.g. all lines from `udevadm info -q all /dev/snd/midiC0D0`.
The remaining task will be to recognize the useful information.

```
<?php

if ($handle = opendir('/dev/snd')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        // detect all entries starting with "midi"
        if (strpos($entry, "midi") === 0) {
            exec(escapeshellcmd("udevadm info -q all /dev/snd/$entry"), $result);
            // $result contains the lines from the udevadm call
            print_r($result);
            print "\n";
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: Good hint, it indeed does show up with a recognisable name. However it points (link) to /dev/snd/controlC1 and not to ../midiC0D1. I´ll have a try with Control1, but why are there multiple devices for the one midi and will they react the same to a read/write operation?

Comment: There is a difference apparently. A simple fopen()/fwrite()/fread() works with /dev/snd/midiC0D0, but not with ../controlC1.... So the original question stays open unless there is some link between control1 <--> midiC0D0 ?
maybe control1 is a audio channel? My device is both a midi as an audio device.

Comment: Apparently those devices are different. I do not have any midi devices, but I will add another approach I came up with to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I already was on that track. The ´all´ option does not show a name, instead I use
udevadm info --attribute-walk --name /dev/snd/midiC1D0

That outputs even more (far more) output and the required substring. This might work. 
Remarkable that a simpler command is not available.....

Answer (score 1):

MIDI devices are listed with their names when you access them through the proper API (ALSA RawMIDI or sequencer):

```
$ amidi -l
Dir Device    Name
IO  hw:2,0    Xonar D2 MIDI
IO  hw:6,0,0  SC-8820 Part A
IO  hw:6,0,1  SC-8820 Part B
IO  hw:6,0,2  SC-8820 MIDI
$ aplaymidi -l
 Port    Client name                      Port name
 14:0    Midi Through                     Midi Through Port-0
 24:0    Xonar D2                         Xonar D2 MIDI
 40:0    SC-8820                          SC-8820 Part A
 40:1    SC-8820                          SC-8820 Part B
 40:2    SC-8820                          SC-8820 MIDI
```

---

USB audio devices get entries in `/dev/snd/by-id/`, which point to the control device of each card:

```
$ ls -l /dev/snd/by-id/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Sep 23 12:51 usb-0582_0007-00 -> ../controlC6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Sep 23 12:51 usb-Roland_EDIROL_UA-1A-00 -> ../controlC5
```

The corresponding MIDI device node has the same card number after the letter `C`:

```
$ ls -l /dev/snd/midiC6*
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116, 12 Sep 23 12:51 /dev/snd/midiC6D0
```

---

Another way to find the card number is to search in the `/proc/asound/card*/usbid` files for the ID of your device:

```
$ cat /proc/asound/card6/usbid
0582:0007
```

---

Alternatively, parse the contents of `/proc/asound/cards`:

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 2 [D2             ]: AV200 - Xonar D2
                      Asus Virtuoso 200 at 0xe800, irq 20
 5 [UA1A           ]: USB-Audio - EDIROL UA-1A
                      Roland EDIROL UA-1A at usb-0000:00:12.2-4.2, full speed
 6 [SC8820         ]: USB-Audio - SC-8820
                      Roland SC-8820 at usb-0000:00:12.0-3, full speed
 ^
 card number
```